# &#8212; special character decoding

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jersey

In our Jersey REST service, we are sending back `&#8212;` to the browser client, as an element in a JSON object.  But the browser JQuery client which is consuming my service, instead of decoding it to a literal `-` is displaying it as `&#8212;`, the encoded value itself.

Wondering if I have to make any settings change in Jersey or JSON resolver for the client browser to understand it as a literal `-`. I am sending the output JSON from Jersey in UTF-16 format. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I wonder if you could use &amp; instead?

Comment: @SidCool, and people reading his comment: the original version of this question made it look like AKSM was trying to send an ampersand. Editing has now made it clear he's trying to send an em dash.

Comment: sorry if my question was misleading. I have edited my question now.

Comment: It would be useful to determine exactly what is sent over the network, so you can tell if the problem is on the client or the server side. Wireshark is a great way to do this. You can also route the traffic through a simple proxy which records the bytes - you can do that with netcat, or by writing it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#8212;` might be valid in HTML or XML. But in JSON it's `\u2014` (2014 is the hexadecimal representation of the decimal number 8212):

```
{
    "trip": "New York \u2014 Chicago"
}
```

You can check it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

BTW: How exactly are you generating the JSON output? You shouldn't need to take care of the details of character encoding. Jersey should do this for you.

**Update:**
Obviously, your initial data is HTML or XML encoded (for whatever reason). So the solution is to undo the encoding before sending it as JSON. Jersey will take care of the rest.

If your data is only HTML/XML encoded for certain characters but not in general, then you have a problem that you need to fix even closer to the source.

Comment: I am using @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) in Resource which is basically converting my JAXB objects to JSON objects. I am using jersey-json.jar in my build. The problem is I get back ``&#8212; from another service call, and I am setting the same value in the outbound JAXB

Comment: What does your data look like in the Java object: Is it `"New York — Chicago"` (correct) or `"New York &#8212; Chicago"` (wrong)?

Comment: In my incoming Java object, I get New York &#8212; Chicago (wrong). I am setting the same value in a JAXB object which inturn is converted to JSON for the client to consume

Comment: undo encoding as in convert it to a literal - and send? I'll have to clean up a lot of such bad data, since I get multiple lists with such data in different places

Comment: Decoding the bad data could be done with `obj.text = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML(obj.text);` (using Apache Commons and provided it's HTML encoded). Or fix the problem at the source.

Comment: we fixed the problem at the source. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending `&#8212` or `&#8212;`? Remember an entity has to have a terminating semicolon.

Comment: It has a terminating semicolon. If I introduce the semicolon here, it gets decoded by the browser in the question display. So I have left the terminating; out, but it is present in JSON output

Comment: Try quoting the string with backticks. That seems to work for me.